# finding the most occurring word/ mode in a row with some null values in postgresql

Tags: database, postgresql, row, average, mode

I have a table that shows a colour which represents the healthiness of an item with each row showing if the total fat/sodium/fiber is a good amount or not.

[image]

my next step would be to get the avg or mode of the colour for an overall color of the food.

My question is how can i get the mode/ most occuring color in that row to show.
Im stuck because they are in rows and im trying to find most occurring colour in that row.

the code is here which calculates the colour

```
SELECT recipe_id, seq, food_id, 
    CASE
        WHEN nf_total_fat IS NOT NULL AND nf_calories IS NOT NULL AND nf_calories <> 0 AND (nf_total_fat * 9) <= (nf_calories/10) * 3  THEN 'green'
        WHEN nf_total_fat IS NOT NULL AND nf_calories IS NOT NULL AND nf_calories <> 0 AND (nf_total_fat * 9) >= (nf_calories/10) * 3.6 then 'red'
        ELSE 'yellow'
    END AS total_fat_color,
    CASE
        WHEN nf_saturated_fat IS NOT NULL AND nf_calories IS NOT NULL AND nf_calories <> 0 AND (nf_saturated_fat * 9) <= (nf_calories/ 10) THEN 'green'
        WHEN nf_saturated_fat IS NOT NULL AND nf_calories IS NOT NULL AND nf_calories <> 0 AND (nf_saturated_fat * 9) >= (nf_calories / 10) * 1.6  THEN 'red'
        ELSE 'yellow'
    END AS saturated_fat_color,
    CASE 
        WHEN nf_sodium <= 104 then 'green'
        WHEN nf_sodium >= 601 THEN 'red'
        ELSE 'yellow'
    END AS sodium_color,
    case 
        when nf_dietary_fiber > 5 then 'green'
        else null
    end as nf_dietary_fiber_color
```

My solution would be to count the amount of 'green' , 'yellow', 'red', in that row and display the colour that was presented the most and if its even with all the colour show 'yellow' as the middle. I just cant seem to figure out how to implement it in the code.